# Struct array types in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Hi I have a function below and every time I compile it gives me the error: "error: assigning to 'struct nodeInfo' from incompatible type 'struct nodeInfo' " and I don't know how to fix it as I've declared an array of the same type. Any help is welcomed.

EDIT: The netTopo[id] = curNode;  Line is causing the issue.

```
struct nodeInfo *getTopology(FILE * file)
{
    int totLinks = 0, digit = 0;

    fscanf(file, "%d", &nodeCount);
    struct nodeInfo netTopo[nodeCount];

    // How many links does node have
    for (int id = 0; id < nodeCount; id++)
    {
        struct nodeInfo
        {
            int n;
            int *links;
        } curNode;

        curNode.n = id;
        fscanf(file, "%d", &totLinks);
        for (int i = 0; i < totLinks; i++)
        {
            curNode.links[totLinks];
            fscanf(file, "%d", &digit);
            curNode.links[i] = digit;
        }
        netTopo[id] = curNode;
    }
    return netTopo;
}
```

Comment: why do you have a struct re-declaration in that loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined `nodeInfo` twice.

Instead of

```
struct nodeInfo {
    int n;
    int *links;
} curNode;
```

try

```
struct nodeInfo curNode;
```

Your first declaration is not shown, so I'm only guessing you intended them to be the same.